# Angular Multi tenant saas - custom domain

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, multi-tenant, saas

I’m trying to develop a saas application like wix but for different purposes.

I can’t think in a solution on how to create one domain per client that register on the plataform.  The user will have the option to use my domain with their name as subdomain or to use their custom domain.

Like client.myydomain.com or client.com

Any help on how I could achieve this?

I just gave wix as example because would be something like it - the user register and can create they website from my platform and choose to use their full domain.

I will use Google cloud as cloud provider.

Hope I was clear .

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you completed research on 1) Registrars 2) DNS Servers 3) SSL Certificates? You will need to interface with vendors for each item. This means writing code to support their APIs.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your reply. I will check those APIs